# How do I get Word 2010 to ignore background fill colours for tables whilst using Windows High Contrast mode

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I need to use Windows 7 in High Contrast mode (black background and light-grey text). Word 2010 nicely conforms to this colour setting in most respects, changing the document colours automatically to white text on a black background, ... except it does not do this for background fill colours in table headers and rows.

The document I need to read has loads and loads of tables where the author has used a light background fill colour for the table headers and columns. This makes the document quite uncomfortable for me to read.

Is there a way to get Word 2010 to ignore table background fill colours, without me having to edit every single table to have no fill colour?